# How do i get rid of Property 'getElementById' does not exist on type 'never[]'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have

```
let accountNumber = (document.getElementById("lash-phone") as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

inside a function in typescript react, but it's throwing this error

```
Property 'getElementById' does not exist on type 'never[]'.  TS2339
```

and this same code works for other screens

Comment: There is nothing to suggest such a problem in your code, can you post more than just that one line? maybe your typescript/project settings? We need a minimal reproducible example to know what went wrong

Comment: Also: you probably shouldn't be using `getElementById` with React. [React has a very specific process for managing DOM updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html), and you shouldn't really be using native DOM element methods with it.

Comment: Do you, maybe, have a variable `document` in the function scope? (And yes, don't `getElementById`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS can't pick up the type of `document` by itself, so you can let it know what's the type:

```js
const lashPhone = (document as Document).getElementById('lash-phone') as HTMLInputElement;
```